# Flutter Android Build APK Error lintvitalrelease

Tags: android, flutter

I try to generate the apk from my flutter app. But every time i become this error code

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':app:lintVitalRelease'.  Could not resolve all artifacts for
>   configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
>       Could not find androidx.test:runner:1.2.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>       Could not find androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

this is the build.gradle file in /app

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the build.gradle in /app/src/

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '0.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "de.***.***"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i find nothing on github or stackoverflow. have anyone a idea ?

Comment: please add your both build.gradle files in your question

Comment: i comment out the two lines
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.1'
//androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.1'
and i can generate a release apk now but i think this cannot be the solution

Comment: Just try changing both your classpaths to the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0' let me know if it works

Comment: sorry it change nothing. the error comes again.

Comment: i found out another solution. another way is to change the versions of the test implementation. androidx.test:runner:1.2.1 to 1.1.1 and espress 3.2.1 to 3.1.1. this solves too. but i'm not sure if that is so good.

Answer (score 0):

try to migrate your project to androidX and if this doesn't work try to downgrade your flutter version to 1.9, I have got the same error and after I downgraded my flutter version it worked.

Comment: i follow this introduction from flutter https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration but if i click on the button "Migrate to AndroidX" a popup show up with the text "No usage found in this Project" and the other tasks (implementent bools in build.gradle) are done. i think my project implement the androidx support.

the newest version of flutter is 1.13. i dont think download is a good solution.

Comment: did you open the android directory alone or have you tried to downgrade flutter to 1.9